# Mathematical procedure for extracting polynomial coefficients.

Tags: polynomials

Is there some nice, formal mathematical way for extracting the $n$-th coefficient of a polynomial

$$P_N(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}a_kx^k \quad\mathrm{?}$$

Something like a function $f_n$ (built from Legendre polynomials??) orthogonal to all $x^k$ except $x^n$ (on some interval a,b):

$$\int_a^b f_n(x)x^k = \delta_{n,k},$$ so that

$$ a_n= \int_a^b f_n(x)P_N(x) \quad ?$$

Or maybe some completely different way?

Thanks.

Comment: Take the $n$th derivative, divide by $n!$, evaluate it at $0$. Voila, the $n$th coefficient.

Comment: Integrate over unit circle against $z^{-n}$.

Comment: As a variation of both of the previous comments: you can (symbolically or numerically) use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) on your polynomial with a suitable contour. A numerical application of this is that you can use FFT to extract polynomial coefficients.

Comment: As an alternative to Cauchy's integral formula:  If you know the value of Pn(x) at N distinct points you can just invert Vandermonde's matrix.

Comment: For more about rrogers' suggestion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Confluent_Vandermonde_matrices

Comment: (Incidentally, using a Vandermonde matrix is how the FFT computes the polynomial coefficients, and in that sense all four of the above suggestions are in spirit the same.)

Comment: And I think there's no Legendre-like sequence of functions that satisfies $\langle f_n, x^k \rangle = \delta^k{}_n$ for an inner product of the form $(f, g) \mapsto \langle f, g \rangle := \int_a^b f g \,dx$, but if you have an upper bound on $N$, then by construction the basis $(f_n)$ dual to $(1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^N)$ with respect to a chosen inner product will satisfy that identity for $n, k \leq N$.